# Getting thrown an error in trying to get json data from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a php file in which there are JSON variables, then I encode them and echo them in the page. I then get that with AJAX from a JS file, but I'm getting thrown an error for some odd reason.

I am using a tutorial to help me make this, but I have tried looking on stackoverflow and other websites.

auth.php:

```
<?php
$userAuth->access = 1;

$userJson = json_encode($userAuth);
echo $userJson;


?>

<script src="auth.js"></script>
```

auth.js:

```
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    const userAuth = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(userAuth.access);
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "auth.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

error:

```
VM100:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (auth.js:4)
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange @ auth.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ auth.js:10
```

My expected result is for me to console log `1`, which is the value of `userAuth.access`, however my actual result is being thrown this error.

It feels like I've tried everything, could this be an issue with my server?

Comment: What do you get if you try to `console.log(this.responseText)`? I'm betting it's not what you're expecting.

Comment: It's not.. `"
  [8]=>
  string(21) "Deputy Prime Minister"
  [9]=>
  string(5) "Dusty"
}
<br><br><br>{"access":1,"uid":76561198143559456}{"pcso":"false","pc":"false","sgt":"true","ins":"false","chiefins":"false","supt":"false","chiefsupt":"false","cmnd":"false","dasstcomm":"false","asstcomm":"false","chiefcst":"false","depcomm":"false","comm":"false"}
<script src="auth.js"></script>`

Comment: It's the whole pages content.

Comment: So, either you need to remove all the rest of the stuff from that page, or you'll need some other way to extract this.

Comment: @tzcoding That's because you have this `<script src="auth.js"></script>` in *auth.php* page. Have a separate page and process your AJAX request there.

Comment: I changed to `test.html`, getting thrown the same error.

Comment: @tzcoding Your page's extension should *.php* i.e. *test.php*, assuming you are processing your AJAX request there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting `die()` after `echo $userJson;` otherwise the script tag at the bottom of the file will also be returned along with the JSON.